# Is it possible to check if or not firebase deliver the notification to a single device in php?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app which uses the MySQL database on server. When new data is inserted into table, my php file pushes notification via Firebase. if firebase deliver the notification to single device the data is saved to the table_1, if firebase cannot deliver the notification the data is saved to table_2. My question is; is it possible to check if or not firebase delivers the notification in php?

FirebaseNotification.php

```
class FirebaseNotification {

public function send($registration_ids, $notification){
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $notification
    );
    return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
}
private function sendPushNotification($fields){

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE){
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }


    curl_close($ch);


    return $result;
}
}
```

PushNotification.php

```
class PushNotification{
private $mTitle;
private $mContent;
private $mProcess;

function __construct($mTitle, $mContent, $mProcess)
{
    $this->mTitle = $mTitle;
    $this->mContent = $mContent;
    $this->mProcess = $mProcess;
}

public function getPushNotification(){
    $res = array();
    $res['ntf']['title'] = $this->mTitle;
    $res['ntf']['content'] = $this->mContent;
    $res['ntf']['process'] = $this->mProcess;

    return $res;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That‘s, unfortunately, currently not possible. From a dedicated backend, you can only check if the message has successfully been delivered to Firebase or if Firebase rejected the message (e.g. when it was malformed or if the target doesn‘t exist).

The delivery from Firebase to the recipient however can not be tracked or checked from a dedicated backend - there are no API endpoints that we could call to do so.

As far as I know this currently does not apply to messages sent via the Firebase Web Console.